# Azure Devops Disable Pull Request Auto-Complete

Tags: autocomplete, azure-devops, pull-request

Azure devops has a "set Auto-Complete" button that allows PRs to be automatically completed if it meets the guidelines set for the repo. How is functionality disabled? I see no toggle switch or settings section devoted to disabling it.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

> How is functionality disabled? I see no toggle switch or settings section devoted to disabling it.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is by designed.  Azure devops does not have such settings to disable the option of auto-complete for all pull request at this moment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you have branch policies on the repository then "Set auto-complete" will always display ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#complete-automatically)).

Is there a reason why you want to disable this option?  If the branch policies are satisfied presumably you're happy for the pull request to be merged manually?  The auto-complete option means developers don't have to sit and wait for a CI build to finish for example.  If you really want manual intervention from a particular developer, you could add them as a [required reviewer to the branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers).  If you want to do this for all repositories in a team project you can use [cross-repo policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/repos/sprint-160-update) (nice [blog](https://medium.com/objectsharp/cross-repo-policies-914d5c066637)). Hope this helps!

Comment: Because when I edit my own file, clicking on the "Create pull request" dialog and selecting the same branch leaves me with the highly-expected information message: "There are no changes to merge between the selected branches."  Huh.  How about that?  But, Azure wants me to create a pull request!

Comment: Is there a way for all PRs to have this auto-enabled so I don't need to click it every time after creating PR?

Comment: @KamilDziedzic sadly not at the moment - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365686/option-to-allow-auto-complete-to-be-the-default-op.html